# How to fix AutoCAD file with a field that starts with a " , "

Tags: arcgis-desktop, autocad

I have a AutoCAD DWG file with a field that start with " , " and the table doesn't open on ArcMap - the error message is invalid field and I can't export the data to shapefile.

How can I fix it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used AutoCADs Block Attribute Manager tool or [BATTMAN command](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-4d9a.htm,topicNumber=d0e201557)- and changed the block tag attribute